# How to update datetime when user input is string

Tags: java

If I have this user input string: `2014/03/31 14:52` how can I check on the hours if more than 13:00 then update the date to the next day 13:00 like this: `2014/04/01 13:00`? If less than 13:00 eg: `2014/03/31 09:52` then I would like to update the datetime to `2014/03/31 13:00`.

Any advice?

Comment: What types are you using? Just Strings? Or something like Joda Time? java.util.Date? Array of bytes?

Comment: user input type is string.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not, [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/) is a sample on how to parse date out of a string and use the `Calendar` class. And you can use `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm` as the format string. Please give it a try.

Comment: yes, I now already can convert string to datetime format. but my problem is I don't know how to get only hours to compare, and if more that 13:00 then I don't know how to update it to the next day and set the time to 13:00 on the next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the hours from the String by substring and then parse that String to Integer then check the value is greater than or less than 13.Then Apply your logic.Below code will help you.

```
    String s="2014/03/31 14:52";
     String s1=s.substring(11, s.length());


     System.out.println(s1);
    String s2[]=s1.split(":");

    if(Integer.parseInt(s2[0])>=13 && Integer.parseInt(s2[1])>0){

        System.out.println("Here apply your logic");


    }
```

If the integer is greater than 13:00,then parse that original String to Date and then simple Add one day using Calender.

Hope this will helps you.

> OR

you can use the below logic to check the hrs and minutes and set the date and time based on your validation

```
    String s="2014/03/31 14:52";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

    Date date = sdf.parse(s) ;// given date
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); // creates a new calendar instance
    calendar.setTime(date);   // assigns calendar to given date 
    int hrs=    calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // gets hour in 24h format

    int min=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    System.out.println("hrs-->"+hrs);
    System.out.println("min-->"+min);

    if(hrs>=13 && min>0){
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        Date newDate=calendar.getTime();
        String newDateS=sdf.format(newDate);
        System.out.println(newDateS);
    }
```

Hope the above code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
class DateTimerTester {

  public static String convert(String input) {    

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    try {
      Date date;
      date = df.parse(input); 
      cal.setTime(date);

      if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 13) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);     
      } else {
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      }
      return df.format(cal.getTime());
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
      e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return "(?!Bad date format!?)";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateTimerTester test = new DateTimerTester();    

    System.out.println(test.convert("2014/03/31 09:52"));
  }
}
```

Java's support for Date and Time is a joke now.